# Is there a better way than dates to correlate the state of two databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency

I have a situation where I need to get a series of objects from two different SQL Server databases for the same period of time.

So if DB1 has a `Car` table, and DB2 has a `Person` table, I want to get all `Cars` and `Persons` up to a point in time `t`.

However, I'd prefer not to be dealing with dates (I don't want to be encountering leap second issues and that kind of thing), and fortunately both databases use `RowVersion` columns. Ideally I'd like to use something like this `RowVersion` as a concurrency token (my `t`) representing a point in time / particular global state, that I could then compare records against.

Unfortunately, `RowVersion` columns are relative to a database, and so not comparable between different databases.

Is there a better solution here? Am I overreacting to not wanting to use dates?

Suggestions appreciated :-)

Comment: I think you are overreacting. Dealing with dates would be much less trouble.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana - I've been bitten before by DST, differences in datetime conversions between systems (this involves external parties), discrepancies between system clocks, and other issues.

Comment: I'm with Muhammad. I haven't worked with sql-server, so am limited here. For myself, the general lesson when dealing with distributed databases has been to have all dates on all systems saved in a common format (GMT). That makes everything comparable. Anything display-wise (say local time) ends up being client representation issues.

Comment: @Glenn - GMT doesn't handle leap seconds or clock discrepancies. We will be servicing around 40 requests a second so issues on a per-second basis are, I believe, likely to bite us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are talking about multiple separate systems, your options are unfortunately limited. You've started in the right place by storing all datetimes in GMT.

Beyond that, `datetime` is really the only appropriate data type to use here. Yes, it will be off between the multiple systems, by fractions of a second, assuming a good, common time sync. But simple network latency when updating records would also cause time differences, anyway, even if the clocks were exactly synced.

`RowVersion` can not help you, for the reason you have noted.

The only other way would be to have a 'sync' table in one or the other database, which relates (logically, not 'physically') to records in either database, and has a common datetime or rowversion that you can use. That would increase the complexity of your querying a little bit, but you already seem to be doing cross-database queries, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, verified that we hadn't overlooked something obvious. What we're going with at the moment is a concatenated RowVersion from the two databases,  which is somewhat like your proposed 'sync' table.

Comment: @MattMitchell I don't know if concatenating the values would work as you expect.

Comment: Why's that? The idea would be that a client returns this concatenated (with seperation) token, so we can identify the shared state of the databases at the time the data was last issued.

Comment: I was under the impression you needed a universal way to sort records across the two dbs.

Comment: Yeah, and a concatenated token would allow that with some logic I believe. It sounds like I'm missing something though? I'll prototype it and see what happens :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have specific time periods that you are dealing with? If so, maybe a common "TimePeriod" table could be linked to each record instead of having to deal with dates?

Comment: It's more about state than time (I need to get all records from `DB1` before `DB2` and can't go and get records from `DB2` that were made after the most recent `DB1` record I have. The problem also is that these are separate databases, so I'd need a TimePeriod table in each database that is somehow synced as well.